# Thread Safety: Maximum efficiency

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Good Evening,

I am trying to understand how I am using multi-threading and how to implement thread-safety in the context.

When I want to achieve maximum speed of my threads do I use:

```
    public void addMarketOrder(MarketOrder marketOrder) {
    if (marketOrder.id != this.id) {
        return;
    }
    synchronized (this) {
        ordered += marketOrder.ordered;
    }
}
```

or just synchronized the entire method?

```
    public synchronized void addMarketOrder(MarketOrder marketOrder) {
    if (marketOrder.id != this.id) {
        return;
    }
    ordered += marketOrder.ordered;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `id`s do not change, the first case is preferable to the second. The first case avoids synchronization if the `id`s do not match. The second case synchronizes even if there isn't any write operation.

Answer (score 1):

What you are hinting towards is double check locking. The correct form is:

```java
    public void addMarketOrder(MarketOrder marketOrder) {
    if (marketOrder.id != this.id) {
        return;
    }
    synchronized (this) {
        if (marketOrder.id != this.id) {
           ordered += marketOrder.ordered;
        }
    }
}
```

Because you shouldn't assume that because the condition became true that it will continue to be true.

Also if you read the id without synchronization it should be volatile because the compiler may optimize away memory reads under certain circumstances and the value that is being held in one thread could be different from another. Also the when not volatile the compiler can change to order of operations assuming a single thread that can make your code misbehave when running with multiple threads.

**Volatility rule:** any variable that is accessed outside of a *synchronized* block by *multiple threads* MUST be *final* or *volatile*. Or you will get thread visibility problems in certain circumstances.

You can also synchronize the whole method without any problem. But synchronizing the whole method will make it less efficient (which could matter if you have a lot of processors and this is a highly contested method).

Comment: The volatile variable rule is slightly different. If a read of a volatile variable, sees a volatile write to that variable, then there is a happens-before edge between that write and read. I'm not sure what you mean with 'masked in the cache'. Caches on modern CPUs are always coherent, and therefor doesn't rely on a variable being volatile.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe the cache is not the correct way to express this. What can happen though is that your variable is sitting on a register in one core, and the value is modified in Ram. Because your compiler has optimized away "unnecessary memory reads" the value in your register (or stack) is no longer correct.

Comment: @pveentjer I tried to fix it to make it clearer. Check out the new edit.

Comment: @pveentjer what you are referring to is an ordering with regard to "happen before" I'd call that the order of operations rule, its not exactly the same as visibility but it's related.

Comment: Happens before implies visibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an efficient multi-threaded system, then do not let threads communicate with each other. If the threads contend for the same data, you can get significant slows downs even if you use fast alternatives like volatiles or Atomics.

I'm not sure which parts of your code need to be thread-safe. If it is only a matter of atomically increasing the counter, then making the 'ordered' field an AtomicLong and calling getAndAdd would be a reasonably fast solution that doesn't make use of any locks.